# Is it possible to display a MKClusterAnnotation callout?

Tags: ios11

Note: I am using iOS11s native mapview annotation clustering.

In a situation where annotations are still clustered at max zoom, in what manner can we show a callout?

I'm showing a pop-over type view to display a list of annotations at the cluster, but calling `selectAnnotation` isn't enough to show a callout for an annotation that is "clustered".

"Something" is selected, but no callout is shown. By something, I just mean that my `didDeselect view` method is called after I touch the mapview.

Answer (score 1):

I ran through the same problem. Seems that they didn't think carefully in that case. You must select the MKClusterAnnotation instead the MKAnnotation that is clustered but it's not simple to get there.

on iOS11 there's a property on MKAnnotationView called `cluster` that as the documentation states is:

`If non-nil this is the annotation view this view is clustered into.`

So in my MKAnnotationView subclass I override the setSelected method and with a weak reference to the mapView you must select the cluster one:

```
//You have weak reference to mapView
weak var mapView: MKMapView?

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        if selected, let cluster = cluster {
            // Deselect the current annotation (Maybe this step is not required, didn't check it)
            if let annotation = annotation {
                mapView?.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)
            }
            // Select the cluster annotation
            if let clusterAnnotation = cluster.annotation {
                mapView?.selectAnnotation(clusterAnnotation, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its actually quite simple. The map view doesn't bother showing a callout if the assigned MKMarkerAnnotationView is not set to show callouts through `.canShowCallout` and also if there are no accessories on the view (that's the important one). If those two conditions are not met then the map can show the title and subtitle on the pin itself. So, here is all you have to do:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
{   

    if annotation is MyAnnotationConformingClass {
       let annotation = annotation as! MKAnnotation

       let view = MKAannotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pinReUserId")
       view.canShowCallout = true
       view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
       return view
    }

    if annotation is MKClusterAnnotation {
        let annotation = annotation as! MKClusterAnnotation
        let view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "ClusterResuseId")
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        return view
    }

    return nil
}
```

By giving the cluster's MKMarkerAnnotationView an accessory and also allowing show callouts, the callout will then be shown. If you remember with older SDKs, the map would not show a callout if you had no title and subtitle set.